# How do I add custom buttons into the balloon android-mapviewbaloons?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I use this nice library for showing balloons: [MapViewBalloons](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-mapviewballoons/)

How do I add any buttons into the balloon?  I would like to add a button with functionality
of adding the current place into favorites! is it possible?
thank you very much.

**Code:**

```
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        itemizedOverlay = new ItemsOverlay(drawable, mapView);          
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(51.5174723*1E6),(int)(-0.0899537*1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "Title", 
                "text");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a button inside your **balloon_overlay.xml**, then in your **BalloonOverlayView.java** class you should have `setupView()` function, inside that function you should add something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloon_overlay, parent);

Button favorite = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

favorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//your code here
});
```

Comment: You are very welcomed, MapViewBalloon is little bit complicated but when you go through the code and try to understand whats happening, it will be very easy for you to customize it for your App. btw you can up vote the answer if you find it useful.